# URL redirect to home page issue in word press site

Tags: pages, redirect, homepage

If i open URL for first time in any browser it is redirecting to home page. Then i open again it is going on actual URL.

Here is the URL
https://dropshipping.vidaxl.com/help-center/

Can any one suggest on this.

How can i open direct https://dropshipping.vidaxl.com/help-center/ inner pages.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me.  The above link took me to the help center.

Comment: Adding the phrase **Wordpress** to the end of any general question, does not make it a Wordpress question.